# JSON API scaling

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I've been looking at JSON API and keep getting hung up on scalability scenarios. Lets say you have a large collection (1000) of models, each with 3 or 4 relationships each.

From my understanding, JSON API requires you to specify **at least** the relationships with their associated id(s) (and optionally sideload the relationship with `include`). If that collection of 1000 models has to do a `JOIN` for every single relationship to be able to populate the valid JSON API payload like below:

```
...
{
  "some_relationship_name": {
    data: [
      { id: 1, type: "derp" }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't see how this can possibly scale in any reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify the `id`s of the relationships. You can just specify the `links` to provide a way to fetch the links. Checkout [the specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships).

So you can do something like this:

```
{
    id: '1'
    type: 'base'
    relationships: {
        relA: {
            links: {
                self: '/base/1/relationships/relA',
                related: '/base/1/relationships/relA/related',
            }
        },
        ...
    }
    attributes: {...}
}
```

So you don't have to JOIN anything you don't directly need. For example in a list you don't join information you only need in the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you can see problem. You have 20 bytes per relations / 4 relations / 1000 records => ~100kB. Existing adapters should have no issues with processing such data fast enough.

If you need to transport less data there are several options. You can add compression but be aware that for such small data it is usually faster to transfer data than to compress them.

Other option is to send only data that you really need. Usually you don't need 1000 records in the web app immediately. So paging and lazy-loading should help you to send only those data that are really required.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I'm not worried about payload size, I'm worried about `JOIN` performance. Normally, with this kind of data, you wouldn't have to include the relationship ids unless you wanted to but to be JSON API compliant you have to.